# random characters in c

Tags: c, random, strcmp

I wrote a program that attempts to "guess" a word by randomly choosing characters.  However, my program is printing characters that are not in my character list.  What is going on here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){

    int index, i;
    time_t t;
    char characters[] = "bdefgir";
    char word[] = "friedberg";
    srand((unsigned)time(&t));
    char result[9] = {0};

    while(strcmp(result, word) != 0){

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            index = rand() % 8;
            result[i] = characters[index];
        }
        printf("Result:\t%s\n", result);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Your `result` isn't null-terminated after filling it; `strcmp` and `printf("%s", ...)` expect null-terminated srings. Make `result` 10 characters long.

Comment: Or change %s to %.9s

Comment: Further, your code may pick the null-terminating character of `characters`, which is 7 chars long, but has size 8: 7 chars plus one null terminator. Picking the null may be by design, but I guess you only want to pick from the seven letters in the character pool.

Comment: You also have a writing error at the 2nd argument of the strcmp() call, although your compiler should advise you!

Comment: In strcmp() function you mistyped **word** as **wort**

Comment: all right, already fixed, originally the variable word had a different name, i changed it later and forgot to change this variable in string compare as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your misspelled variable `wort` it should be `word`. Also you have to have `result` array containing 9 characters (like your word `"friedberg"`) and ending with a `'\0'` character (so total number of characters is in fact 10).

The correct solution would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int index, i;
    time_t t;
    char characters[] = "bdefirg";

    char word[] = "friedberg";

    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    char result[10];
    result[9] = '\0';

    while (strcmp(result, word) != 0) {

        for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            index = rand() % 7;
            result[i] = characters[index];
        }
        printf("Result:\t%s\n", result);

    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Letters are repeated many times in the `result` whilce using default number generator. For example getting rand numbers from /dev/urandom on *nix systems + extending characters array to duplicate characters that are duplicated in the original word would make things faster.

Comment: @chux I think you're right, I removed that part of my answer.

Comment: that solved the problem thanks, but it takes still too long to match the word, character pool would be a solution i suppose